# custom rmeta - forest plot generation does not work: " 'x' and 'units' must have length > 0"

Tags: r, plot, r-forestplot

I tried to generate a "forest plot" without summary estimates using the rmeta package. However, using ?forestplot and then starting from the description or the example does not help, I am always getting the same error. I would assume that it is a simple one that has to do with the matrix/vector lengths somewhat not lining up but I kept changing and adjusting and still cannot find the error...

Here is the example code:

```
tabletext<-cbind(c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA),
             c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA),
             c("variable1","subgroup","2nd", "3rd", "4th", "5th"),
             c(NA,"mean","1.8683639", "2.5717301", "4.4966049, 9.0008054")
             )
tabletext
png("forestplot.png")
forestplot(tabletext, mean = c(NA, NA, 1.8683639, 2.5717301, 4.4966049, 9.0008054), lower = c(NA, NA, 1.4604643, 2.0163468, 3.5197956, 6.9469213), upper = c(NA, NA, 2.3955105, 3.2897459, 5.7672966, 11.7288609), 
is.summary = c(rep(FALSE, 6)), zero = 1, xlog=FALSE, boxsize=0.75, xticks = NULL, clip = c(0.9, 12))
dev.off()
```

Error message:

```
 clip = c(0.9, 12))
Error in unit(rep(1, sum(widthcolumn)), "grobwidth", labels[[1]][widthcolumn]) : 
  'x' and 'units' must have length > 0
 dev.off()
```

Any help is very much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

This works with the forestplot-package although you need to remove the `xticks=NULL`:

```
tabletext<-cbind(c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA),
                 c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA),
                 c("variable1","subgroup","2nd", "3rd", "4th", "5th"),
                 c(NA,"mean","1.8683639", "2.5717301", "4.4966049, 9.0008054")
)

png("forestplot.png")
forestplot(tabletext, 
           mean = c(NA, NA, 1.8683639, 2.5717301, 4.4966049, 9.0008054), 
           lower = c(NA, NA, 1.4604643, 2.0163468, 3.5197956, 6.9469213), 
           upper = c(NA, NA, 2.3955105, 3.2897459, 5.7672966, 11.7288609), 
           is.summary = c(rep(FALSE, 6)), zero = 1, 
           xlog=FALSE, boxsize=0.75,  clip = c(0.9, 12))
dev.off()
```

Gives (I recommend some polishing before submitting for publishing):

[image]